# Remove pipe between given words in a text

Tags: c#

I have a text and in the text I have to remove a pipe character that's in between 2 given words.
I have searched and tried but without any succes and now I could use some help.

The text is:

> Klantcode:|Aanhef en voorletters: Dhr. A.|Tussenvoegsel en achternaam: B.V.|E-mailadres: test@test.nl|Straat: De Straat|Huisnummer / toevoeging: 00|Postcode: 000AA|Woonplaats: PLACE|Telefoonnummer: 012345678|Bank- of gironummer: 00000000|Machtigingen: Ik verleen hierbij tot wederopzegging machtiging voor de incasso van de eenmalige kosten en periodieke abonnementskosten inclusief eventuele aanvullende diensten aan Diensten BV.|Nieuwsbrief: U wilt de maandelijkse nieuwsbrief ontvangen|Voorwaarden: U bent akkoord met onze voorwaarden|Huidig telefoonnummer behouden: Ja|Huidige nummer: 012345678|Huidige provider: Anybody, geen eenmalige kosten EDL/Film1/Sport1 behouden, |geen comfort bellen.|Ingangsdatum abonnement: Zo snel mogelijk|Abonnement:Alles-in-1 Glas Standaard;* Basic TV;* Internet 150Mbps;* VoIP-First Bellen|Extra:* Glasmodem € 0,00;* HD Digitale Ontvanger € 0,00;* Aansluitkosten € 0,00|Per maand: Eerste 3 maanden € 00,00, daarna € 00,00;* Verzend- en administratiekosten € 00,00;* Totaal eenmalig € 00,00|$<

The code I have for now is:

```
public string RemoveBetween(string baseText, string begin, string end)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\|", begin, end));
        return regex.Replace(baseText, string.Empty);
    }

o.Product = RemoveBetween(orderText, "Huidige provider:", "|Ingangsdatum");
```

This piece of code does not give me the wanted result. It does not remove the pipe character.
Is there someone who could help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Because you don't have substitution values in your format string (`{0}`). Go debug your code and inspect your variables.

Comment: is this the really issue that you need? Why you have to specify begin and end words?

Comment: @Glauco Cucchiar: I need begin and end words because the text contains several pipe characters. And the pipe characters between the begin and end words are the only ones that need to be removed. Otherwise the text will break when I want to import it in a gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format is:

```
text       = any character other than ':' or '|'
key        = text
value      = text
kvp        = key ':' value '|'
dictionary = {kvp}
```

and you are trying to remove `|`'s that are incorrectly intermixed with the values, you can use the following regex:

```
// Remove any '|' that follow a '|' without an intervening ':'
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:\|)([^:|]*)(?=\|)");
return regex.Replace(baseText, "$1");
```

Example:

```
a:b|c|c:d|e:f|g|l:m|n:z|h|k| -> a:bc|c:d|e:fg|l:m|n:zhk|
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a dictionary to me:

```
var s = "a:b|c:d";
var sKvps = s.Split('|');

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var sKvp in sKvps)
{
    var parts = sKvp.Split(':', 2);
    dict.Add(parts[0], parts[1].Trim());
}
```

Then you can replace values with:

```
dict["Huidge provider"] = "foo";
```

To go backwards (to a string):

```
s = string.Join("|", dict.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}"));
```

---

To fix your code, if you prefer a regex ([explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5C%7C%7B0%7D%3A%28%3F%3A+%3F%29%29%28%5B%5E%7C%5D*%29%28%5C%7C%29)):

```
public string UpdateProperty(string baseText, string property, string newValue)
{
    // look for "|PropertyName: value|" and split it into parts for replacement
    Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"(\|{0}:(?: ?))([^|]*)(\|)", property));
    return regex.Replace(baseText, string.Format("$1{0}$3", newValue));
}

o.Product = UpdateProperty(orderText, "Huidige provider", "new value");
```

I really wouldn't recommend such a thing since it does not escape text into the regex.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and answer. But your solution does not give me the wanted result. Because the split is based on all the pipes in the text, the pipes between the given strings "Opmerking:" and "|Bankrekening" don't get removed. And that's what I need. Only the pipes between the 2 given strings need to be removed. The other pipes need to stay.

Comment: Neither "Opmerking:" nor "|Bankrekening" are present in your example.  Please supply an example "before" and "after".

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The start string is "Huidige provider:", the end string is "|Ingangsdatum". Between those 2 strings all the pipe characters need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the pipe and loose the `string.format`  (not sure why that's there):

```
var strRegex = @"\|";
var myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var strTargetString = @"Klantcode:|Aanhef en voorletters: Dhr. A.|Tussenvoegsel en achternaam: B.V.|E-mailadres: test@test.nl|Straat: De Straat|Huisnummer / toevoeging: 00|Postcode: 000AA|Woonplaats: PLACE|Telefoonnummer: 012345678|Bank- of gironummer: 00000000|Machtigingen: Ik verleen hierbij tot wederopzegging machtiging voor de incasso van de eenmalige kosten en periodieke abonnementskosten inclusief eventuele aanvullende diensten aan Diensten BV.|Nieuwsbrief: U wilt de maandelijkse nieuwsbrief ontvangen|Voorwaarden: U bent akkoord met onze voorwaarden|Huidig telefoonnummer behouden: Ja|Huidige nummer: 012345678|Huidige provider: Anybody, geen eenmalige kosten EDL/Film1/Sport1 behouden, |geen comfort bellen.|Ingangsdatum abonnement: Zo snel mogelijk|Abonnement:Alles-in-1 Glas Standaard;* Basic TV;* Internet 150Mbps;* VoIP-First Bellen|Extra:* Glasmodem € 0,00;* HD Digitale Ontvanger € 0,00;* Aansluitkosten € 0,00|Per maand: Eerste 3 maanden € 00,00, daarna € 00,00;* Verzend- en administratiekosten € 00,00;* Totaal eenmalig € 00,00|$<";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your solution removes all the pipes in the text. And that is not the desired result.